# NuxtJS, VueX - How to minimize the code to the maximum

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I would like to simplify my code in VueX and component a bit. How can I do this?
I would like to use this code quite often, which is why I need to minimize it to the maximum

component

```
            this.$store.commit(
              "notifications/changeText",
              "Pomyślnie zmieniono avatar !"
            );
            this.$store.commit("notifications/changeStyle", "success");
            this.$store.commit("notifications/changeStatus", true);
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.$store.commit("notifications/changeStatus", false);
            }, 5000);
```

store/notifications.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  activeStyle: "",
  active: false,
  text: ""
});

export const mutations = {
  changeText(state, text) {
    state.text = text;
  },
  changeStyle(state, style) {
    state.activeStyle = style;
  },
  changeStatus(state, status) {
    state.active = status;
  }
};

export const getters = {
  text(state) {
    return state.text;
  },
  style(state) {
    return state.activeStyle;
  },
  status(state) {
    return state.active;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to wrap that code in a function.

But if it'd be normal function you'd have to **import it everywhere** you'd like to use that code. So the best place to put that function is somewhere you have access all the time without importing anything.

The answer is **Vuex**.

But where? **Actions.** Why `actions`? At the top of Vuex [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) we can see the differences between `actions` and `mutations`. And one of those differences is perfect match for our use case:

`Instead of mutating the state, actions commit mutations.`

So let's wrap that piece of code in an actions function!

```
//store/notifications.js
export const actions: {
  our_lovely_action({ commit }) { //you can rename this function to fit your needs
    commit(
      "changeText",
      "Pomyślnie zmieniono avatar !"
    );
    commit("changeStyle", "success");
    commit("changeStatus", true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      commit("changeStatus", false);
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

**How does this even work?**

Every `action function` you create in Vuex gets automatically passed one argument - `context`. This `context` let's you access the state, mutations and getters.

**So how do you call this action?**

Super easy.

```
this.$store.dispatch("notifications/our_lovely_action");
```

That's it.

P.S: To be sure you can check the full code here:

```js
//store/notifications.js
export const state = () => ({
  activeStyle: "",
  active: false,
  text: ""
});

export const mutations = {
  changeText(state, text) {
    state.text = text;
  },
  changeStyle(state, style) {
    state.activeStyle = style;
  },
  changeStatus(state, status) {
    state.active = status;
  }
};

export const getters = {
  text(state) {
    return state.text;
  },
  style(state) {
    return state.activeStyle;
  },
  status(state) {
    return state.active;
  }
};

export const actions {
  actions: {
    our_lovely_action({ commit }) { //you can rename this function to fit your needs
      commit(
        "changeText",
        "Pomyślnie zmieniono avatar !"
      );
      commit("changeStyle", "success");
      commit("changeStatus", true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        commit("changeStatus", false);
      }, 5000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are like a God. Thank you so much